# Interface Builder is not letting me delete a button

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

To clarify: I have a view/vc which is designed as an orphaned scene in IB in the storyboard it is used within. This view has a button with an image, a height and width constraint, a left and top constraint. There is a table below it with top, left, bottom, right constraints set to 0. A seperate VC loads this view, sets its width to half the screen and animates it coming in and sets its delegate.

All's honky dory. Now, we wanted to edit the sizing of the button and some miscellaneous things. I noticed the constraints seemed to not be getting applied in simulator. I then, after a while of playing with constraints and losing my mind, decided that maybe something more fundamentally wrong was occurring so i decided to delete the button and see where the table below it is getting placed with it's constraints set.

Then, nothing. The button is still there. I have looked to see if I accidentally c/ped it, and I have not. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Clean the project and delete the app on simulator.

Comment: Did you also try to delete it from the hierarchical view on the left?

Comment: The button was not in the hierarchical view, either @joakim

Comment: @Mercurial, if you want to officially answer the question, you have earned my upvote and acceptance of answer. I would never have thought deleting the app from the simulator was the answer and I wasted a ton of time thinking something else was wrong.

Comment: @Erik You just witnessed a glorious IB bug then :)

Comment: @Erik Sure, for the sake of question being marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean the project and delete the app on simulator.